# jQuery.html() is not working when trying to populate a ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I spent an hour or so to get this working. Please help me. 
Find the link to jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/gbd52cw8/1/

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var filledList = '<li style="display: none;"><div class="post-container"><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff"></div><div class="post-content"><div class="title-business"><h3 id="title" class="post-title">Miami Ohio Redhawks at Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets</h3><a id="business" target="_blank" href="http://www.stubhub.com/wisconsin-vs-miami-ohio-9-12-2015-9196040">StubHub</a></div><p id="desc">Wisconsin Badgers - Miami Ohio Redhawks Football Tickets - Buy and sell Miami Ohio Redhawks vs Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets for 12 September at Camp Randall Stadium in Madison on StubHub!</p><p id="price">Price: $40.86</p></div></div></li><li style="display: none;"><div class="post-container"><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff"></div><div class="post-content"><div class="title-business"><h3 id="title" class="post-title">Northwestern Wildcats at Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets</h3><a id="business" target="_blank" href="http://www.stubhub.com/wisconsin-vs-northwestern-11-21-2015-9196054">StubHub</a></div><p id="desc">Wisconsin Badgers - Northwestern Wildcats Football Tickets - Buy and sell Northwestern Wildcats vs Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets for 21 November at Camp Randall Stadium in Madison on StubHub!</p><p id="price">Price: $70.11</p></div></div></li><li style="display: none;"><div class="post-container"><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff"></div><div class="post-content"><div class="title-business"><h3 id="title" class="post-title">Rutgers Scarlet Knights at Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets</h3><a id="business" target="_blank" href="http://www.stubhub.com/wisconsin-vs-rutgers-10-31-2015-9196052">StubHub</a></div><p id="desc">Wisconsin Badgers - Rutgers Scarlet Knights Football Tickets - Buy and sell Rutgers Scarlet Knights vs Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets for 31 October at Camp Randall Stadium in Madison on StubHub!</p><p id="price">Price: $68.94</p></div></div></li><li style="display: none;"><div class="post-container"><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff"></div><div class="post-content"><div class="title-business"><h3 id="title" class="post-title">Hawaii Warriors at Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets</h3><a id="business" target="_blank" href="http://www.stubhub.com/wisconsin-vs-hawaii-9-26-2015-9196043">StubHub</a></div><p id="desc">Wisconsin Badgers - Hawaii Warriors Football Tickets - Buy and sell Hawaii Warriors vs Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets for 26 September at Camp Randall Stadium in Madison on StubHub!</p><p id="price">Price: $49.81</p></div></div></li><li style="display: none;"><div class="post-container"><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff"></div><div class="post-content"><div class="title-business"><h3 id="title" class="post-title">Purdue Boilermakers at Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets</h3><a id="business" target="_blank" href="http://www.stubhub.com/wisconsin-vs-purdue-10-17-2015-9196049">StubHub</a></div><p id="desc">Wisconsin Badgers - Purdue Boilermakers Football Tickets - Buy and sell Purdue Boilermakers vs Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets for 17 October at Camp Randall Stadium in Madison on StubHub!</p><p id="price">Price: $66.6</p></div></div></li>';

    var simple = '<strong>OHOYOYOY</strong>';

    $("#all-rests").html(filledList);
    //$("#all-rests").html(simple);


    });
```

Comment: please share your html code also

Comment: use `append()` function

Comment: You realize all the LI's are ***display none***, and you can't see them but they are added just fine in your fiddle ?

Comment: you need to add jQuery library to the jsfiddle demo. It is working with simple string, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gbd52cw8/10/). There must be problem with `filledList` value, please check the markup inside string as you have `display:none` for first `li`. Remove it  and try, it should work, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gbd52cw8/12/).

Comment: From your jsfiddle it seems you have not  added jquery.js and all your Li's are displayed none ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show the child elements as all `li` elements are hidden:

```
$("#all-rests").html(filledList);
$("#all-rests").children().show();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gbd52cw8/4/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you're adding new elements in the DOM, the inline style of those elements is set to `display:none`.

The content you are throwing in DOM is added to the `ul`, but it is invisible.

You are styling the `li`s as `display: none`.

```
var filledList = '<li style="display: none;">...
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Remove those styles and you can see the elements in DOM.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qseuz05m/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var filledList = '<li><div class="post-container"><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff"></div><div class="post-content"><div class="title-business"><h3 id="title" class="post-title">Miami Ohio Redhawks at Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets</h3><a id="business" target="_blank" href="http://www.stubhub.com/wisconsin-vs-miami-ohio-9-12-2015-9196040">StubHub</a></div><p id="desc">Wisconsin Badgers - Miami Ohio Redhawks Football Tickets - Buy and sell Miami Ohio Redhawks vs Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets for 12 September at Camp Randall Stadium in Madison on StubHub!</p><p id="price">Price: $40.86</p></div></div></li><li ><div class="post-container"><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff"></div><div class="post-content"><div class="title-business"><h3 id="title" class="post-title">Northwestern Wildcats at Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets</h3><a id="business" target="_blank" href="http://www.stubhub.com/wisconsin-vs-northwestern-11-21-2015-9196054">StubHub</a></div><p id="desc">Wisconsin Badgers - Northwestern Wildcats Football Tickets - Buy and sell Northwestern Wildcats vs Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets for 21 November at Camp Randall Stadium in Madison on StubHub!</p><p id="price">Price: $70.11</p></div></div></li><li ><div class="post-container"><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff"></div><div class="post-content"><div class="title-business"><h3 id="title" class="post-title">Rutgers Scarlet Knights at Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets</h3><a id="business" target="_blank" href="http://www.stubhub.com/wisconsin-vs-rutgers-10-31-2015-9196052">StubHub</a></div><p id="desc">Wisconsin Badgers - Rutgers Scarlet Knights Football Tickets - Buy and sell Rutgers Scarlet Knights vs Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets for 31 October at Camp Randall Stadium in Madison on StubHub!</p><p id="price">Price: $68.94</p></div></div></li><li ><div class="post-container"><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff"></div><div class="post-content"><div class="title-business"><h3 id="title" class="post-title">Hawaii Warriors at Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets</h3><a id="business" target="_blank" href="http://www.stubhub.com/wisconsin-vs-hawaii-9-26-2015-9196043">StubHub</a></div><p id="desc">Wisconsin Badgers - Hawaii Warriors Football Tickets - Buy and sell Hawaii Warriors vs Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets for 26 September at Camp Randall Stadium in Madison on StubHub!</p><p id="price">Price: $49.81</p></div></div></li><li ><div class="post-container"><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff"></div><div class="post-content"><div class="title-business"><h3 id="title" class="post-title">Purdue Boilermakers at Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets</h3><a id="business" target="_blank" href="http://www.stubhub.com/wisconsin-vs-purdue-10-17-2015-9196049">StubHub</a></div><p id="desc">Wisconsin Badgers - Purdue Boilermakers Football Tickets - Buy and sell Purdue Boilermakers vs Wisconsin Badgers Football Tickets for 17 October at Camp Randall Stadium in Madison on StubHub!</p><p id="price">Price: $66.6</p></div></div></li>';

  var simple = '<strong>OHOYOYOY</strong>';

  $("#all-rests").html(filledList);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Hi</p>
  <ul id="all-rests"></ul>
</body>
```